# SSIS ETL Transform-Load How To Handle Create / Update (i.e. UPSERT) for Foreign Key Table Data?

Tags: sql-server, architecture, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I am performing ETL on a set of `Office`, `Employee`, `Location` tables by following the standard practice of bringing all the data into Staging tables, first by way of **Extract** packages, and then performing **Transform-Load** on each of the staging table to get the data into the respective table(s).

In each of my **Transform-Load** SSIS Packages, I am performing **CUD** ( **Create, Update, Delete**) by using `MERGE JOIN` and `CONDITIONAL` Splits.

This works fine when the data in Staging table is **1-to-1** with the corresponding real table. In the scenario below (see image) the `SampleLocation` table is 1-to-1 with the `StageSampleLocation` table.

The trouble I am having is deciding how to handle a situation where the Staging table has data that will go into the Foreign key table(s).

#### The Problem explained

If you take a look at the following database diagram...

[image]

The data from `StageSampleOffice` goes into `SampleOffice` for fields that have Office data. In addition to office data, the `StageSampleOffice` has Person data -- in this example, `OfficeManagerName` field will need to be looked up in the FK table `SamplePerson`. If the name  doesn't exist in `SamplePerson` table, this name will need to be inserted in `SamplePerson` first, and the `PersonId` PK value for that person will be retrieved and stored as the FK value in the row for the imported Office in the `SampleOffice` table, in my Data Flow Task.

Similarly, for the address info in `StageSampleOffice`, the details will need to be looked up in the `SampleLocation` FK table, and if the address doesn't exist, a new one needs to be inserted with the corresponding values from `StageSampleOffice`. Once that is done, the `LocationId` for the address will be stored as FK in the `SampleOffice` table.

As you can see, data for `SampleLocation` and `SamplePerson` could come into the system from 2 or more sources. In the example above, for `SampleLocation` I get a Location data file that only has the addresses. I also get addresses as part of Office records from various office types, that come in the `StageSampleOffice` table.

#### What I have tried so far

I have already separated the **Extract** workflows from the Transform-Load workflows. I have 1 extract package per staging table, that essentially reads data from the source (flatfile or table), truncates the staging table, and imports everything as-is into the staging table.

I am thinking that

- for Person data that is present in the `StageSampleOffice`, I will first insert the data into the `StageSamplePerson` table (not shown in diagram) and then execute the **Transform-Load** Package for `SamplePerson` that will do the Create or Update for those Persons and
- for Location data that is present in the `StageSampleOffice`, I will first insert the data into the `StageSampleLocation` table (not shown in diagram) and then execute the **Transform-Load** Package for `SampleLocation` that will do the Create or Update for those Location.

This way, all the FK rows will be present in the respective table when the flow returns to my main package that does the Transform-Load for the `SampleOffice` table.

Is this a good idea, or is there a better way.

Thank you!

Comment: your ssis will have 1) execute sql task to truncate stage table 2) data flow task to load all data into stage table 3) execute sql task to call a stored procedure that does your CUD operations (create a stored procedure to do this)

Comment: I already have that. Did you read my question fully??

Answer (score 1):

Seems like "6 of one, half-dozen of the other" to me.

Either way you're eventually checking every person and every location to see if it is already in the final destination table and doing an insert or not.

Whether you "pre-condense" them in the staging tables or not the workload will be the same.  I would go with the approach that seems more intuitive to you, because that will be the one that you will find more maintainable in the future.